# How to write unit test in angular for setTimeout function and activeElement?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I want to write a unit test case for the following function:

```
onfactorblur():void{
  var that=this;
  setTimeout(function(){
    var target=document.activeElement;
    if(target.tagName=="BUTTON"){
      if(target.textContent=="CONTINUE"){
        that.onContinueClick();
      }
      else{
        that.activeModal.close();
      }
     }
   },.5);
 }
```

I am new to angular unit testing and never faced a scenario where I had to test setTimeout within a function. I have tried:

```
    it('Should close the modal if target element is button',fakeAsync(()=>{
    spyOn(component,'onContinueClick');
    spyOn(component.activeModal,'close');
    tick(1);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(()=>{
    //What should I write here
      })
    }));
```

Comment: You should extract the function in setTimeOut and test it individually.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan thanks...but I have already tested onContinueClick and activeModal.close() . Can you demonstrate your suggestion please .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fakeAsync`, you can call `tick(500)` to simulates the asynchronous passage of time
more details here https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#async-test-with-fakeasync